# String split in C# causing an object reference error

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to split the `string` tab or space. This my code:

```
string s = File.ReadLine();

string[] str =s.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t'});"

"Soccer SOCCER 11" //this is the content of variable s.
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What am I doing wrong? Please help me to debug this.

Comment: what is the path `ReadLine` reads from ?(assuming `File` is a `StreamBuilder`)

Comment: Yes,file is a stream reader

Comment: what is the path ?

Comment: For conformation I used  Streamwriter and its wring the the currect text "Soccer SOCCER 11" to other file.

Comment: path is "TextFiles\\Sports1.txt"

Comment: `TextFiles\\Sports1.txt` doesn't seem like a valid path to me ? is it in your resource ?

Comment: When you get the error, it should list the location where the error occurred (file, line number, class, method). Which line is giving the error? Can you split the lines up into smaller statements to determine where the error is?

Comment: I am using his for reading the text "<add key="SportPath" value="C:\\Users\\kusha\\source\\repos\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\TextFiles\\Sports.txt" />"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your line of code for the split is correct, i just tried it and it works as expected.

The error must be when reading from the file, i saw your comment about writing to a file before reading, try to call the Dispose() method on the StreamWriter before trying to read from it, otherwise you can get errors like this.

Comment: string Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SportPath"];
            

            using (System.IO.StreamReader File = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path)) {
                while ((File.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string s = File.ReadLine();
                    string[] str =s.Split(new Char[] {' ', '\t'});
                    UpdateRecords.Sport(str);}  this the code I am using to read the text file.

Comment: Now i get the error, you are reading two times the line, on the second read you get the error. Your code should be:             string Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SportPath"];
            using (System.IO.StreamReader File = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path))
            {
                string readString = File.ReadLine();
                while (readString != null)
                {
                    string[] str = readString.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' });
                    UpdateRecords.Sport(str);
                }
            }

Comment: Yes, I was reading the file twice I fixed it and its working.Thank you.